# magento 2 setup:upgrade gives some error:

Tags: magento2

magento 2 setup:upgrade gives some error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1823 Failed to add the foreign key constraint 'table name/CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID' to system tables, query was: ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_int` ADD CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`)  ON DELETE CASCADE, ADD CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID` UNIQUE KEY (`entity_id`,`attribute_id`,`store_id`), ADD INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID` (`attribute_id`),ADD INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_STORE_ID` (`store_id`), ADD INDEX `CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_INT_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID_VALUE` (`attribute_id`,`store_id`,`value`)

how to solve the issues.